# How to get dynamic path in java

Tags: java

```
String s = "cmd /c " + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath()
            + "mysql-5.6.26-winx64/bin/mysqldump -u root -password database_name>" + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath()
            + "backup/backup.sql";
```

I dont want static code
I want to choose dynamic path on java.

Comment: which file paths do you mean? if you meant "mysql-5.6.26-winx64/bin/mysqldump -u root -password database_name>" you can pass it through program or vm arguments and process from there

Comment: how to get files path dinamicly

Comment: From where do you want to get them? Command-line arguments, property file, environment variable, system property, user prompt, database, ...?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the code from main method, pass the variables as program arguments. Read these arguments in the method and create the path.

For example

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "cmd /c " + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath() + args[0] +  "-u   root -password database_name>" + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath() + args[1];
}
}
```

For any application VM arguments can be used.

```
 String s = "cmd /c " + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath() + System.getProperty("sysProp1") +  "-u   root -password database_name>" + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath() + System.getProperty("sysProp2");
```

These variables `sysProp1` or `sysProp2` can be set using -DsysProp1=value1 -DsysProp2=value2 when starting the server / application.

Or if they are required at multiple places in the application

Create a class to hold these values

```
public class HolderClass {
     public static String value1 = null;
     public static String value2 = null;
}
```

Now, in the method where these values are available (in main method for example), set the values,

```
HolderClass.value1 = "value received"
HolderClass.value2 = "Other value received"
```

At the point where this value is required, use as

```
 String s = "cmd /c " + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath() + HolderClass.value1 +  "-u   root -password database_name>" + GeneralMethods.getFilesPath() + HolderClass.value2;
```

Comment: Then VM arguments can be used link :- http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/whats-the-difference-between-program-arguments-and-vm-arguments.html. You can pass the variables around to the method which requires these.

Comment: I want to get when users  select the file  path in java application
I will reach these code and
I use the file path on dinamicly

Comment: You can use the HolderClass example stated above, which will allow to access the path.